# ActiveRecord `from_csv` method - howto make it more sexy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, csv, fastercsv

I have written method to load data to DB from CSV. For me it's a little bit unsexy and it's far away from DRY:

```
  def self.from_csv(data)
    c = Company.new
    FasterCSV.parse(data) do |row|
      c.name = row[0]
      c.street = row[1]
      c.street_number = row[2]
      c.apartament_number = row[3]

      c.city = row[4]
      c.post_code = row[5]
      c.post_office_city = row[6]

      c.nip = row[7]
      c.regon = row[8]
      c.vatin = row[9]
    end
  end
```

How to make it more sexy or may be there is already any lib to load data?

Comment: This should probably be on codereview.se

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put [a sexy lady](http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=people/naked%20ladies) on top of it:

```
#          ___
#   _  _.-"_< }
#    ""--"" 7(
#          /())
#         / )/
#        ^ ( \
#          / /
#         /.'
#        //
# ______/L___ sexii
def self.from_csv(data)
  #...
end
```

But, seriously, the only problem I see with your code is that you cannot rearrange attributes easily because you will have to manually update all indexes. I'd prefer to have an ordered list of attributes in an array and use some Ruby's dynamic method calling:

```
def self.from_csv(data)
  company = new
  row = CSV.parse_line(data)
  [:name, :street, :street_number, :apartament_number,
   :city, :post_code, :post_office_city,
   :nip, :regon, :vatin].each_with_index do |name, i|
    company.send(:"#{name}=", row[i])
  end
  company
end
```

Also note that you need to return a constucted company instance at the end otherwise you will get some random value when calling `Company.from_csv`.

Comment: ha..ha..really loved your `sexy lady`..:D

Answer (score 1):

```
c = Company.new
cols = ["name", "street", "street_number", "apartament_number", "city", "post_code", "post_office_city", "nip", "regon", "vatic"]

FasterCSV.parse(data) do |row|
  cols.each_index { |i| c.send("#{cols[i]}=", row[i]) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this lightweight wrapper to load CSV files:

https://github.com/stackpilot/loady

It works with ruby 1.9 and uses the standard ruby CSV library (formerly known as FasterCSV).

You do this with it:

```
Loady.csv "/your/file.csv" do |row|
  Company.create row.to_attributes [:name, :street, :street_number, ...]
end
```

Comment: And what if I wanna run it without saving file, only text uploaded?

Comment: If you don't want to read from a file, then you should not use the Loady.csv method. Instead, you can use CSV.parse directly, like in your question. The "to_attributes" method might still be helpful though. See https://github.com/stackpilot/loady/blob/master/lib/loady/array.rb

Comment: The link above is no longer valid. See https://github.com/teeparham/loady/blob/master/lib/loady/attribute_array.rb